# How to pass xml parameters to a flash swf file using URL?

Tags: xml, url, flash

I need to pass XML structure to Flash SWF file using URL eg. www.example.com/flash.swf?xml=XXXXX

Here I do not want to pass file. how can I pass XML then?

I tried encoding, but not worked.

Comment: What do you mean by "tried encoding, but not worked"? What did you try exactly and how did it fail?

Comment: encoding means URL encoding.